Why qiskit QAOA is not accurate at all with Clique problem?
I am trying to solve clique problem with provided qiskit code below:
 self.clique = Clique(self.graph())
 self.qp = self.clique.to_quadratic_program()
 qp2qubo = QuadraticProgramToQubo()
 qubo = qp2qubo.convert(self.qp)
 self.qubitOp, self.offset = qubo.to_ising()

 qaoa = QAOA(sampler=Sampler(), optimizer=optimizer,
                        callback=store_intermediate_result, reps=3)
 result = qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(operator=self.qubitOp)
            print(result.eigenvalue.real)

here for optimizer what i tried was COBYLA, SPSA, SLSQP. And it yields poor result for graph with only 4 nodes.
Graph example is here (gset format):
4 4
1 2 1
1 3 1
2 3 1
2 4 1

what I should get is result [1, 1, 1, 0] with eigenvalue -3.5, but what I get occasionally were [1 0 1 0] with eigenvalue -2.**. I am wondering is how accurate the qaoa is and why sometimes even the result is correct ([1, 1, 1, 0]), the eigenvalue yielded is far from accuracy???
I tried some classical optimizers, and also tried AerSimulator and different ansatz.
